# Advantage of adding costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer plugin to global costmap

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was going through [this](http://wiki.ros.org/husky_navigation/Tutorials/Husky%20Move%20Base%20Demo) Husky Navigation tutorial. This tutorial allows us how to navigate the Husky bot **without** using a map.

It has 3 `yaml` files for configuring the costmaps -  `costmap_global_laser.yaml` (for global costmap) , `costmap_local.yaml` (for local costmap) and `costmap_common.yaml` (for both global and local costmap).

This is how `costmap_local.yaml` looks-

```
global_frame: odom
rolling_window: true

plugins:
  - {name: obstacles_laser,           type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
  - {name: inflation,                        type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

This is  how `costmap_global_laser.yaml` looks-

```
global_frame: odom
rolling_window: true
track_unknown_space: true

plugins:
  - {name: obstacles_laser,           type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
  - {name: inflation,                       type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

Why have we added an `costmap_2d:ObstacleLayer` to the costmap_global_laser.yaml  when it is already included in the costmap_local.yaml? Are there any advantages in terms of path planning?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368417/advantage-of-adding-costmap_2d::obstaclelayer-plugin-to--global-costmap/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2020-12-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "costmap_2d:ObstacleLayer" in global costmap will "add" obstacle into global costmap, which resultes that global planner will plan a path to avoid that obstacle

---

Originally posted by [drtritm](https://answers.ros.org/users/50806/drtritm/) with karma: 187 on 2021-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-01-12**:
Makes sense. Thanks!